# CI Event Calendar not showing current month data until clicking next/prev

Tags: codeigniter

With this code below CI calendar working fine to view data from database, when click next/prev. but for first time when calendar open with default current month and doesn't show any data from database, cause in ulr after the controller name there is no `year, month` parameter. I really can't find that what I missed actually.

Controller:

```
    class my_calendar extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('logindatamodel');
        $this->load->model('my_calModel');
    }
    public function showcal($year=null, $month=null){
        $user_data['userinfo'] = $this->logindatamodel->login_data();
        $data['calendar']=$this->my_calModel->generate($year,$month);

        $this->load->view('common/header', $user_data);
        $this->load->view('common/menu', $user_data);
        $this->load->view('my_calendar',$data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
  class my_calModel extends CI_Model{
    var $conf;
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->conf = array(
            'start_day'       => 'saturday',
            'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url'   => base_url().'my_calendar/showcal'
            );
    }

    public function get_calendar_data($year, $month){
        $query= $this->db->select('scheduleDate, event_data')
                     ->from('tbl_calendar')
                     ->like('scheduleDate',"$year-$month",'after')
                     ->get();
        $cal_data=array();

        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $index=ltrim(substr($row->scheduleDate,8,2),'0');
            $cal_data[$index]=$row->event_data;
        }
        return $cal_data;
    }

    public function generate($year, $month){
        $this->load->library('calendar', $this->conf);
        $cal_data=$this->get_calendar_data($year, $month);
        return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$cal_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note you should name your controller with first letter only uppercase for class and filename http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world and also same with models http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, the original poster may have gotten it fixed without coming back to tell the forum. But for others who are stuck, here is how I fixed a similar problem. Your controller should look like so:

```
 public function showcal($year=null, $month=null){

    if (!$year) {
        $year = date('Y');
    }
    if (!$month) {
        $month = date('m');
    }
    $user_data['userinfo'] = $this->logindatamodel->login_data();
    $data['calendar']=$this->my_calModel->generate($year,$month);

    $this->load->view('common/header', $user_data);
    $this->load->view('common/menu', $user_data);
    $this->load->view('my_calendar',$data);
    $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```

Take note of the initialisation for month and year. The reason is because, since the month and year passed as arguments in the function are set to null, if the month and year aren't entered in the url, the browser assumes there is no date. But by initialising the month and year, the current month and year will always be passed to the controller and model, then the right data would be fetched.

Enough of the rambling. Please original poster should check and accept.

Yours truly.